# Youtube v3 Data Api get category Id by channel id

Tags: api, youtube

I'm using youtube v3 data api and I would like to get channel category id using only the channel id, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible get the category *(or categories)* from a given channel_id.

The way you can do this is using the "channel" API as follows:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=<CHANNEL_ID>&part=topicDetails&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>
```

The following information was taken from the [YouTube Data API - official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list):

- **id:** Id of the YouTube Channel you want retrieve the category *(or categories)*.
- **key:** your API key.
- **part:** The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more search resource properties that the API response will include. For this case, I added `topicDetails`.

You can use the [try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?#try-it) functionality available in the official documentation for test the `channels` API requests.

For an specific scenario, I used the [try-it functionality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22topicDetails%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw%22%7D#try-it) using the channel "PiewDiePiew", and the results for this channel are:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/SZVZPmfCMK51FYGbt3QJc0cSuS8\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [{
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/k9uIVtL0Ha-_i_u38vFWu3Xws0A\"",
        "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
        "topicDetails": {
            "topicIds": [
                "/m/0bzvm2",
                "/m/0bzvm2"
            ],
            "topicCategories": [
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_culture"
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

The categories of the channel will be shown in the `topicCategories` section of the API response.